# Has the parameter $\frac{1}{\sqrt{2(n-1)}}$ a name?

Tags: definition

Has the parameter $\displaystyle \frac{1}{\sqrt{2(n-1)}}$ a name? $n=\text{number of observations}$

Comment: No, except if you consider "reciprocal of the standard deviation of a chi-square random variable with $n-1$ degrees of freedom", as a "name".

Comment: I like to note that $n$ is a parameter "sample size", while $\displaystyle \frac{1}{\sqrt{2(n-1)}}$ would at most be some statistical measure, which I never heard of.

Comment: Normally I'd call that something like 'the expression', 'the term' or 'the constant factor' rather than 'the parameter', which has a very particular meaning in statistics.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No.

(Body must have at least 30 characters;)

Comment: I'll remember that answer, it's endlessly recyclable here. +1.